# Display totals and percentage in stacked bar chart using DataFrame.plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart, plot-annotations

My data frame looks like below:

| Airport | ATA Cost | Destination Handling | Custom | Total Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PRG | 599222 | 11095 | 20174 | 630491 |
| LXU | 364715 | 11598 | 11595 | 387908 |
| AMS | 401382 | 23562 | 16680 | 441623 |
| PRG | 599222 | 11095 | 20174 | 630491 |

Using below codes it gives a stacked bar chart:

```
import pandas as pd

# sample dataframe
data = {'Airport': ['PRG', 'LXU', 'AMS', 'PRG'],
        'ATA Cost': [599222, 364715, 401382, 599222],
        'Destination Handling': [11095, 11598, 23562, 11095],
        'Custom': [20174, 11595, 16680, 20174],
        'Total Cost': [630491, 387908, 441623, 630491]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot columns without Total Cost
df.iloc[:, :-1].plot(x='Airport', kind='barh', stacked=True, title='Breakdown of Costs', mark_right=True)
```

[image]

How to add the totals (separated by thousands 1,000) over each stacked bar chart? How to add `%` for each segments in the stacked bar chart?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `plt.text` to place the information at the positions according to your data.

However, if you have very small bars, it might need some tweaking to look perfect.

```
df_total = df['Total Cost']
df = df.iloc[:, 0:4]
df.plot(x = 'Airport', kind='barh',stacked = True, title = 'Breakdown of Costs', mark_right = True)

df_rel = df[df.columns[1:]].div(df_total, 0)*100

for n in df_rel:
    for i, (cs, ab, pc, tot) in enumerate(zip(df.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(1)[n], df[n], df_rel[n], df_total)):
        plt.text(tot, i, str(tot), va='center')
        plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(np.round(pc, 1)) + '%', va='center', ha='center')
```

[image]

EDIT: Some arbitrary ideas for better readability:

shift the total values to the right, use 45° rotated text:

```
    plt.text(tot+10000, i, str(tot), va='center')
    plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(np.round(pc, 1)) + '%', va='center', ha='center', rotation=45)
```

[image]

switch between top- and bottom-aligned text:

```
va = ['top', 'bottom']
va_idx = 0
for n in df_rel:
    va_idx = 1 - va_idx
    for i, (cs, ab, pc, tot) in enumerate(zip(df.iloc[:, 1:].cumsum(1)[n], df[n], df_rel[n], df_total)):
        plt.text(tot+10000, i, str(tot), va='center')
        plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(np.round(pc, 1)) + '%', va=va[va_idx], ha='center')
```

[image]

label only bars with 10% or more:

```
if pc >= 10:
    plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(np.round(pc, 1)) + '%', va='center', ha='center')
```

[image]

...or still print them, but vertical:

```
if pc >= 10:
    plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(np.round(pc, 1)) + '%', va='center', ha='center')
else:
    plt.text(cs - ab/2, i, str(np.round(pc, 1)) + '%', va='center', ha='center', rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. it works very well. is there a way to avoid text overlapping each other?

Comment: I don't know of an automatism, but perhaps rotating by 45 degree might help as a first approach?

Comment: if I do not plot the number < 0.1, how to adjust the code?

Comment: What do you mean - do you want to reduce the digits of precision right to the decimal sign to only print the integer values?

Comment: I mean i want to hide those text overlapping each other. it's also good to make the % with 0 decimal place

Comment: you could change `str(np.round(pc, 1))` to `str(int(np.round(pc, 0)))`

Comment: the more important thing for me here is to hide those small % overlapping each other.

Comment: honestly: the easiest and most effective way would be simply to plot a (vertical) bar-chart instead of a hbar-chart

Comment: I have to plot horizontally because i have a big chart. can we conditional plot the text (i,e. plot if the % is greater than 10%)

Comment: You could even still label smaller values too, but these vertical rotated, so that they fit better in...

Answer (score 0):

- This is more easily implemented with [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html), which is thoroughly described in [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804).

#### Data and Imports

```py
import pandas as pd

# load the dataframe from the OP and set the x-axis column as the index
df = df.set_index('Airport')

# calculate the percent for each row
per = df.iloc[:, :-1].div(df['Total Cost'], axis=0).mul(100).round(2)
```

#### Horizontal Bars

```py
# plot
ax = df.iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6))

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)

# iterate through the containers
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # get the current segment label (a string); corresponds to column / legend
    label = c.get_label()
    
    # create custom labels with percent
    labels = per[label].astype(str) + '%'
    
    # add the annotation
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center', rotation=-90, fontsize=7)

# annotate the top of the bar with the full count
_ = ax.bar_label(ax.containers[-1], label_type='edge', rotation=-90)
```

[image]

#### Vertical Bars

```py
ax = df.iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6), rot=0)

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)

# iterate through the containers
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # get the current segment label (a string); corresponds to column / legend
    label = c.get_label()
    
    # create custom labels with percent
    labels = per[label].astype(str) + '%'
    
    # add the annotation
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center', fontsize=7)

# annotate the top of the bar with the full count
_ = ax.bar_label(ax.containers[-1], label_type='edge')
```

[image]

#### Vertical Bars - Not Stacked

- It is typically better to not stack, because the relative sizes of segments are easier to compare.

```py
# plot
ax = df.iloc[:, :-1].plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10, 6), rot=0, width=0.85)

ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)

# iterate through the containers
for c in ax.containers:
    
    # get the current segment label (a string); corresponds to column / legend
    label = c.get_label()
    
    # create custom labels with percent
    labels = per[label].astype(str) + '%'
    
    # add the percent
    ax.bar_label(c, labels=labels, label_type='center', fontsize=7)

    # add the count to the top of the bar
    _ = ax.bar_label(c, label_type='edge')
```

[image]