# How to show percentages on the stacked bar chart in python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, stacked-chart

I have dataframe which is in below form:

```
data = [['M',0],['F',0],['M',1], ['M',1],['M',1],['F',1],['M',0], ['M',1],['M',0],['F',1],['M',0], ['M',0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Gender','label'])
print (df)
  Gender  label
0       M      0
1       F      0
2       M      1
3       M      1
4       M      1
5       F      1
6       M      0
7       M      1
8       M      0
9       F      1
10      M      0
11      M      0
```

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart which should percentage as the annotation on the chart.
Code below to create stacked bar chart:

```
df.groupby('Gender')['label']\
    .value_counts()\
    .unstack(level=1)\
    .plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

I am not sure how to get percentages on the chart.

Thanks ina dvance

Answer (score 4):

I can offer you this solution:

I have created a new DataFrame,df2, that contains the percentages that need to be painted.

The values ​​of df2, have been ordered to correspond correctly with the index i that refers to the different bars.
This allows you to paint each value in the right place.

`get_xy` obtains the x and y coordinates of the bottom corner of each bar.

`get_width` gets the width of each bar.

`get_height` gets the length of each bar.

To paint the percentages a loop is used. Each turn of a loop refers to a bar. The center of each bar is half the width and length. `kx` and `ky` are used to slightly correct the position.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
data = [['M', 0], ['F', 0], ['M',1 ], ['M', 1], ['M', 1], ['F', 1], ['M', 0], ['M', 1], ['M', 0], ['F', 1], ['M', 0], ['M', 0]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Gender','label'])
F_Serie = df.groupby('Gender')['label'].value_counts()['F']
M_Serie = df.groupby('Gender')['label'].value_counts()['M']
M_Serie = M_Serie*(100/M_Serie.sum())
F_Serie = F_Serie*(100/F_Serie.sum())
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([list(F_Serie), list(M_Serie)]), index = ['F', 'M'], columns = [0, 1])

ax = df.groupby('Gender')['label'].value_counts().unstack(level=1).plot.barh(stacked=True, figsize=(10, 6))
# Set txt
kx = -0.3
ky = -0.02

values = []
for key in df2.values:
    values = values + list(key)
# ordering the values    
val = values[1:3]
values.pop(1)
values.pop(1)
values = val + values


for i,rec in enumerate(ax.patches):
    ax.text(rec.get_xy()[0]+rec.get_width()/2+kx,rec.get_xy()[1]+rec.get_height()/2+ky,'{:.1%}'.format(values[i]/100), fontsize=12, color='black')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but graph is not showing % marks on the chart. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What does 40, 80 indicates in the ax.text()?

Comment: the first two fields correspond to the x and y coordinates referring to the figure where you want to write the text, therefore 40 and 80 refer to y coordinates

Comment: I have added another option to set the position of the text automatically, I use get_xy to get the x and y coordinates of the bottom point of each rectangle, you can check this here:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html

Finally, add to each coordinate the width and height respectively and adjust this position using kx and ky.

You can try to vary kx and ky.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, is it possible to do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495982/display-totals-and-percentage-in-stacked-bar-chart-using-dataframe-plot.

Comment: Do you want horizontal or vertical bars? Do the axes units want them in percentages?

Comment: I want horizontal bar and want to show percentages on the bars as shown in the above url.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts you are putting in. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have updated the code and the image. Tell me if you need any modification!

Comment: What was the mistake?

Comment: I had to `pop (1)` twice because the array positions are updated. 
A value was repeated in the values ​​list.
I have updated the code too.