# Display totals and percentage in stacked DataFrame.plot bar

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, machine-learning, data-mining

I have a small DataFrame (it has only 2 columns: "Gender" whose values are "Male" and "Female" and "MaritalSatus" whose values are "Single", "Married" and "Divorced"). Data distribution is summarized here bellow:

```
    Gender  MaritalStatus   Tot.
    Male    Single          225
    Male    Married         296
    Male    Divorced        143
    Female  Single          137
    Female  Married         222
    Female  Divorced        94
```

With the following code I am able to draw a stacked bar plot:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pclass_xt = pd.crosstab(df["Gender"], df["MaritalStatus"]) 
pclass_xt.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.xlabel("Gender")
plt.ylabel("count")
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.show()
```

Here is my output:

[image]

I'd like to add the totals over each stacked bar and the % for each segments in the stacked bar chart. Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is a very detailed, involved approach here: https://www.w3resource.com/graphics/matplotlib/barchart/matplotlib-barchart-exercise-16.php

Comment: The output does not correspond to the code sample you have given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display totals and percentage in stacked bar chart using DataFrame.plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495982/display-totals-and-percentage-in-stacked-bar-chart-using-dataframe-plot)

Answer (score 1):

The graph can be obtained by using the `matplotlib` `bar` function and then adding text. The code for the plot is as follows (I have made the assumption that the data is stored in `data.csv` file):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
display(df)

pclass_xt_group = df.groupby(by=["Gender", "MaritalStatus"]).count()
pclass_xt_group = pclass_xt_group.T
display(pclass_xt_group)

#Get values from the group and categories
groups = ['Female', 'Male']
female = pclass_xt_group['Female'].to_numpy()[0]
male = pclass_xt_group['Male'].to_numpy()[0]

divorced = [pclass_xt_group['Female']['Divorced'][0], pclass_xt_group['Male']['Divorced'][0]]
married = [pclass_xt_group['Female']['Married'][0], pclass_xt_group['Male']['Married'][0]]
single = [pclass_xt_group['Female']['Single'][0], pclass_xt_group['Male']['Single'][0]]

#add colors
colors = ['#FF9999', '#00BFFF','#C1FFC1']

# The position of the bars on the x-axis
r = range(len(groups))
barWidth = 1

#plot bars
plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
ax1 = plt.bar(r, divorced, color=colors[0], edgecolor='white', width=barWidth, label="divorced")
ax2 = plt.bar(r, married, bottom=np.array(divorced), color=colors[1], edgecolor='white', width=barWidth, label='married')
ax3 = plt.bar(r, single, bottom=np.array(divorced)+np.array(married), color=colors[2], edgecolor='white', width=barWidth, label='single')
plt.legend()

# Custom X axis
plt.xticks(r, groups, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel("Count")

for r1, r2, r3 in zip(ax1, ax2, ax3):
    h1 = r1.get_height()
    h2 = r2.get_height()
    h3 = r3.get_height()
    plt.text(r1.get_x() + r1.get_width() / 2., h1 / 2., "%.2f" % (h1/(h1+h2+h3)), ha="center", va="center", color="white", fontsize=16, fontweight="bold")
    plt.text(r2.get_x() + r2.get_width() / 2., h1 + h2 / 2., "%.2f" % (h2/(h1+h2+h3)), ha="center", va="center", color="white", fontsize=16, fontweight="bold")
    plt.text(r3.get_x() + r3.get_width() / 2., h1 + h2 + h3 / 2., "%.2f" % (h3/(h1+h2+h3)), ha="center", va="center", color="white", fontsize=16, fontweight="bold")
plt.show()
```

The plot obtained is as follows:
[image]

The essence of the code was inspired from https://medium.com/@priteshbgohil/stacked-bar-chart-in-python-ddc0781f7d5f